# how to parse empty tokens from a comma-separated data?

Tags: java

I have some large files with comma separated data in them.  Something like:

```
firstname,middlename,lastname
James,Tiberius,Kirk
Mister,,Spock
Leonard,,McCoy
```

I'm using a StringTokenizer to parse the data:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sLine, ",");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
  String sTok = st.nextTokens;
  tokens.add(tok);
}
```

The problem is, on lines with no middle name, I only get two tokens, { "Mister", "Spock" }, but I want three tokens, { "Mister, "", "Spock" }

QUESTION: How do I get empty tokens included when parsing my comma separated data?

Thanks!

Comment: replace all consecutive commas with ",<space>,"...a patch but should work if commas as fixed for deliminator...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
String[] split = sLine.split(",");
for (String s : split) {
    System.out.println("S = " + s); //Note there will be one empty S
    tokens.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use split(",") instead of a StringTokenizer:

```
String[] aux = sLine.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
    String sTok = aux[i];
    tokens.add(sTok);
}
```

You can see in the documentation that StringTokenizer is a legacy class and is only kept for retro-compatibility:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` method, but pass `-1` as the second argument to keep empty strings

```
sLine.split(",", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of Splitter of [Guava Splitter](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)

And you can create an splitter with or without omit empty Strings.

```
//Example without omit empty Strings (default)
Splitter splitterByComma = Splitter.on(",");
Iterable<String> split = splitterByComma.split("Mister,,Spock");

//Example omitting empty Strings
Splitter splitterByComma = Splitter.on(",").omitEmptyStrings();
Iterable<String> split = splitterByComma.split("Mister,,Spock");
```